# Create angled elements using html and css only

Tags: html, css

How to create the offer div with a background color using html and css only ?

[image]

**What I'm asking is width and height of the offer div should be same as in picture.**
I created this using html and CSS. However part of div is hidden in my solution because offer div has a larger width and height.

Code I have written :

```css
.offer-text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -39px;
  left: -36px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 72px;
  width: 75px;
  background: #f44336;
  transform: rotate(-43deg);
}

.offer-text {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 21px;
  line-height: 124px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-text-wrapper">
    <span class="offer-text"> Offer </span>
</div>
```

Edit :

Because width and height of offer-text-wrapper is larger, I'm having below issue when I added that to the bootstrap grid.

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, can you clarify what is wrong with it?

Comment: It works fine. But what I want is width and height of offer-text-wrapper to be same as in picture. In my solution larger part of offer-text-wrapper is hidden. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code snippet, it's basically just changing dimensions and position until you're happy with it.

Is this what you mean?

```css
.offer-container { /* added container to show effect better */
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.offer-text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -29px;
  left: -40px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 72px;
  width: 95px;
  background: #f44336;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.offer-text {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 114px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-container">
  <div class="offer-text-wrapper">
    <span class="offer-text">Offer</span>
  </div>
</div>
```